# A Device Riley Riddle

Tags: riddle, word

```
My prefix may be what a device can be on
My infix is most likely in your device
My suffix is what devices can be
My whole is a reverse motion
```

Hint:

> Think more about the whole, as it is probably easier since there won't be that many things that fill in the answer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are:

> Counterclockwise

My prefix may be what a device can be on

> Many devices can be on a COUNTER

My infix is most likely in your device

> Many devices (like phones) include a CLOCK function

My suffix is what devices can be

> Sadly, Siri is more WISE than many people I know ...

My whole is a reverse motion

> Counterclockwise is the reverse of the regular motion of a clock

Comment: Yes! Nice job. +1

Answer (score 4):

Long shot, but I think that the answer could be

> Recoiled

Prefix

> Rec - recording? (not sure about this one)

Infix

> Coil - coils are used in most electronic devices

Suffix

> Oiled (OLED) - OLED monitors, TVs, displays

Whole

> [Recoil](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recoil) is a "backward movement of a gun when it is discharged"

Comment: For your suffix, the plain interpretation of the word seems to work too.

Comment: Check the hint, your answer it is not right, but my details for the prefix, infix, and suffix, are not immediately apparent and can be applied to other things as well. +1 :)

Comment: Edited the last line, maybe that helps.